# PDAL: How to combine two range filters with an OR (instead of AND)?

Tags: pdal

I have a point cloud with two additional attributes (dimensions): `Planarity` and `Linearity`.

I want to filter this point cloud based on the following condition: `Planarity > 0.90 OR Linearity > 0.90`

However, it seems that this can not be done with the `filters.range` filter, as no OR condition is possible when using different attributes (dimensions).

For instance:

```json
...
{
    "type":"filters.range",
    "limits":"Planarity[0.90:],Linearity[0.90:]"
},
...
```

filters only those points which pass **both** conditions, i.e. the conditions are logically combined by an AND (not an OR).

Does anybody have a solution/workaround for this issue?

Edit:

I found a solution using the `filters.mongo` filter:

```json
...
{
    "type": "filters.mongo",
    "expression": {
        "$or": [
            {
                "Linearity": {
                    "$gt": 0.90
                }
            },
            {
                "Planarity": {
                    "$gt": 0.90
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
...
```